# Bootstrap push and pull columns gives unexpected behavior for mid and large screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Goal is to view bootstrap page on mid to large screen as `col-screen-8` (screen-lg-md,sm,xs) as image to left. `col-screen-4` as form to right in single row and on next row `col-screen-12` as content at center eg. Banking.For mobile view or small screens I want to view `Image at top -> Banking at middle -> Form as bottom` in mobile view vertically.I am able to achive the mobile view as expected and see result by shrinking window. [push pull demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bpEFe/772/).When it comes to mid or big screen it is not working as expected.When i played using `push-pull` bootstrap classes they are just moving left to right.

What is happening:
When i increase screen size Image column is getting bigger and Form and Banking remain at bottom

What is expected:

When i increase screen size Image should move to left side with size `col-screen-8` as Image, Form `col-screen-4` at right and content Banking `col-screen-12` as Banking to the next row at bottom. Mobile view must not affected.

Thanks.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I make of it, `.col-XX-pull-N` and `.col-XX-push-N` classes only 
 add left and right negative margins, which means you can only use them to offset columns left and right on the same `.row`. You can't push a column on the next row. You're only pushing it outside the layout. It won't magically wrap.

You should add a class to your special row and use flexbox's `order` property to re-order columns at desired widths:

```css
.reorder-md {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .reorder-md-last {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row reorder-md">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 reorder-md-last">
      <div class="alert alert-info text-center">Banking</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">Form</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note `.reorder-md` and `.reorder-md-last` are custom classes I added. So don't expect `.reorder-lg` to work in Bootstrap. You need to add the CSS for reordering yourself, as well as match Bootstrap's responsive breakpoints.